# Does it make sense to randomly project high-dimensional data into low-dimensional ones in outliers detection?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, outliers, unsupervised-learning

I have some high-dimensional data from which I want to detect outliers. I know that if I'm working with low-dimensional data, I can cluster and then check if a data point belongs to a cluster, or calculate the average distance from it to its k nearest neighbors, etc. But I can't do these on high-dimensional data because of the curse of dimensions.

So I think maybe I can randomly project the high-dimensional data to lower dimensional ones, and check if the projections of a data point are outliers in most of the transformed dataset. My assumption is that an outlier in higher-dimension should also appears to be outliers in most projections to lower-dimension.

For example, randomly generate some projections from [image: R^4] (suppose we have the curse of dimensions in [image: R^4]) to [image: R^2] (where we can cluster by traditional methods), denoted by [image: P1, P2, P3 .. Pn] (all of them are [image: 2x4] matrices with random elements). Suppose we want to detect outliers in [image: a1, a2 .. an]. If for many [image: k], [image: Pk*am] is an outlier in [image: Pk*a1, Pk*a2 .. Pk*an], than [image: am] is an outlier.

Does it makes sense?

Comment: Are you aware of the set of techniques known as dimensionality reduction?

Comment: @delnan Thank you. I'm reading about it now.

Answer (score -1):

The typical way to perform anomaly detection would be to perform dimensionality reduction using [principle component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). The idea is similar to what you describe, but it uses linear algebra to make a smart choice of the exact way to perform the projection. Doing that guarantees that minimal amount of information is lost with the projection.